# Is it possible to draw resolution proof tree in beamer

Tags: beamer, qtree

How to draw a resolution tree such as [the example here](http://www.cs.miami.edu/~geoff/Courses/TPTPSYS/FirstOrder/SyntacticRefinements.shtml)

[image]

Comment: Asking a question like this is not likely to get many answers. There are plenty of `tikz-qtree` questions and answers on the site, and the `tikz-qtree` documentation has an example of how to draw a tree upside down.  If you show us a working document with what you're having trouble with, perhaps people can help you.

Comment: No need to down vote below `-1`, especially to a new member

Comment: Hi math :) and [welcome to TeX.sx](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436). In its current form, your question might not receive many answers. Please take a look at the [How to Ask](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/how-to-ask)-page and try to improve your question according to the guidance found there. if possible please add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228). If you have questions about what to do or if you don't quite understand what this means, please ask for clarification using the `add comment` function.

Comment: Many thanks, guys. That tree can be written in latex?

Answer (score 7):

The tree can be easily done using [`TikZ`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/pgf):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc,fit,trees}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[
  grow'=up,
  level 1/.style={sibling distance=14em},
  level 2/.style={sibling distance=6em}]
\node (f) {False} 
child { node (1l) {$p(a)$}
  child {node (2ll) {$\neg p(a)$}}
  child {node (2lr) {$p(a)\vee p(b)$}}
}
child {node (1r) {$\neg p(a)$}
child {node (2rl) {$p(X)\vee r(X)$}}
child {node (2rr) {$\neg r(b)$}}
};
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

The only thing that might not be trivial is to draw the closed paths surrounding some groups of formulas; one possible approach here would be to use [`Jake's answer`](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/27185/3954) to [padded boundary of convex hull](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/27171/3954):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc,fit,trees}

\newcommand{\convexpath}[2]{
[   
    create hullnodes/.code={
        \global\edef\namelist{#1}
        \foreach [count=\counter] \nodename in \namelist {
            \global\edef\numberofnodes{\counter}
            \node at (\nodename) [draw=none,name=hullnode\counter] {};
        }
        \node at (hullnode\numberofnodes) [name=hullnode0,draw=none] {};
        \pgfmathtruncatemacro\lastnumber{\numberofnodes+1}
        \node at (hullnode1) [name=hullnode\lastnumber,draw=none] {};
    },
    create hullnodes
]
($(hullnode1)!#2!-90:(hullnode0)$)
\foreach [
    evaluate=\currentnode as \previousnode using \currentnode-1,
    evaluate=\currentnode as \nextnode using \currentnode+1
    ] \currentnode in {1,...,\numberofnodes} {
-- ($(hullnode\currentnode)!#2!-90:(hullnode\previousnode)$)
  let \p1 = ($(hullnode\currentnode)!#2!-90:(hullnode\previousnode) - (hullnode\currentnode)$),
    \n1 = {atan2(\x1,\y1)},
    \p2 = ($(hullnode\currentnode)!#2!90:(hullnode\nextnode) - (hullnode\currentnode)$),
    \n2 = {atan2(\x2,\y2)},
    \n{delta} = {-Mod(\n1-\n2,360)}
  in 
    {arc [start angle=\n1, delta angle=\n{delta}, radius=#2]}
}
-- cycle
}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[
  grow'=up,
  level 1/.style={sibling distance=14em},
  level 2/.style={sibling distance=6em}]
\node (f) {False} 
child { node (1l) {$p(a)$}
  child {node (2ll) {$\neg p(a)$}}
  child {node (2lr) {$p(a)\vee p(b)$}}
}
child {node (1r) {$\neg p(a)$}
child {node (2rl) {$p(X)\vee r(X)$}}
child {node (2rr) {$\neg r(b)$}}
};
\draw[cyan!70!black] \convexpath{f,1l.west,1r.east}{13pt};
\draw[red!70!black] \convexpath{1r,2rl.west,2rr.east}{12pt};
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

You have access to many resources related to `TikZ`:

- The [`pgf manual`](http://mirrors.ctan.org/graphics/pgf/base/doc/generic/pgf/pgfmanual.pdf).
- The [`minimal introduction to TikZ`](http://cremeronline.com/LaTeX/minimaltikz.pdf).
- The [`examples gallery`](http://texample.net/tikz/examples/) at TeXample.net
- The numerous examples on this site.