# How to highlight sub-matrix / nodes with tikz?

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-matrix

I'm trying to highlight a box of different cells of a matrix that I'm rendering. Currently, this highlights the entire matrix in green. What I would like to do is within that box highlight another series of nodes. For instance, I would like to draw a box / circle / etc around N1, N2, N3, and N4. Is there a relatively pain free way of going about doing this?

```
\begin{tikzpicture}[
   inner/.style={circle,draw=blue!50,fill=blue!20,thick,inner sep=3pt},
   outer/.style={draw=green,fill=green!20,thick,inner sep=10pt, column sep=1cm, row sep=1cm}
]
  \matrix (A) [matrix of nodes, outer, nodes={inner}]{
       &    & N5 & N9  \\
       & N2 & N6 & N10 \\
    N1 & N3 & N7 & N11 \\
       & N4 & N8 &     \\
   };
```

EDIT: I was looking for a solution that could both enclose and highlight a subset of nodes, which makes it differ from the duplicate questions a bit.

Comment: Possible duplicate: [Highlight elements in the matrix](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/40028/5764)

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format.

Comment: With highlight, do you mean just draw a path surrounding those nodes (in which case this is a duplicate of the answer linked by Werner in his comment), or do you also want to draw *and* fill the path?

Comment: I would like to draw and fill the path.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since filling the path is required here, this is not an exact duplicate of [Highlight elements in the matrix](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/40028/5764), but we can use some of the ideas there. In the code below I show two options; the first one using a simple `\draw` and the other one using the `fit` library; since, in both cases, a filling color is added, the filling overwrites the nodes and they must be "redrawn", which is easily accomplished with a `\foreach` loop:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix,fit}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[
   inner/.style={circle,draw=blue!50,fill=blue!20,thick,inner sep=3pt},
   outer/.style={draw=green,fill=green!20,thick,inner sep=10pt, column sep=1cm, row sep=1cm}
]
  \matrix (A) [matrix of nodes, outer, nodes={inner,draw}]{
       &    & N5 & N9  \\
       & N2 & N6 & N10 \\
    N1 & N3 & N7 & N11 \\
       & N4 & N8 &     \\
   };
\draw[rounded corners] 
  ([xshift=-10pt]A-3-1.north west) -- 
  ([xshift=-10pt,yshift=10pt]A-2-2.north west) -- 
  ([xshift=10pt,yshift=10pt]A-2-2.north east) -- 
  ([xshift=10pt,yshift=-10pt]A-4-2.south east) -- 
  ([xshift=-10pt,yshift=-10pt]A-4-2.south west) -- 
  ([xshift=-10pt]A-3-1.south west) -- cycle;
\end{tikzpicture}\hfill   
\begin{tikzpicture}[
   inner/.style={circle,draw=blue!50,fill=blue!20,thick,inner sep=3pt},
   outer/.style={draw=green,fill=green!20,thick,inner sep=10pt, column sep=1cm, row sep=1cm}
]
  \matrix (A) [matrix of nodes, outer, nodes={inner,draw}]{
       &    & N5 & N9  \\
       & N2 & N6 & N10 \\
    N1 & N3 & N7 & N11 \\
       & N4 & N8 &     \\
   };
\node[draw,fit={(A-3-1) (A-2-2) (A-4-2)}] {};
\end{tikzpicture}

\begin{tikzpicture}[
   inner/.style={circle,draw=blue!50,fill=blue!20,thick,inner sep=3pt},
   outer/.style={draw=green,fill=green!20,thick,inner sep=10pt, column sep=1cm, row sep=1cm}
]
  \matrix (A) [matrix of nodes, outer, nodes={inner,draw}]{
       &    & N5 & N9  \\
       & N2 & N6 & N10 \\
    N1 & N3 & N7 & N11 \\
       & N4 & N8 &     \\
   };
\draw[cyan,fill=cyan!20,rounded corners] 
  ([xshift=-10pt]A-3-1.north west) -- 
  ([xshift=-10pt,yshift=10pt]A-2-2.north west) -- 
  ([xshift=10pt,yshift=10pt]A-2-2.north east) -- 
  ([xshift=10pt,yshift=-10pt]A-4-2.south east) -- 
  ([xshift=-10pt,yshift=-10pt]A-4-2.south west) -- 
  ([xshift=-10pt]A-3-1.south west) -- cycle;
\foreach \Pos/\Nodo in {A-3-1/N1,A-2-2/N2,A-3-2/N3,A-4-2/N4}
  \node[inner] at (\Pos) {\Nodo};
\end{tikzpicture}\hfill
\begin{tikzpicture}[
   inner/.style={circle,draw=blue!50,fill=blue!20,thick,inner sep=3pt},
   outer/.style={draw=green,fill=green!20,thick,inner sep=10pt, column sep=1cm, row sep=1cm}
]
  \matrix (A) [matrix of nodes,outer, nodes={inner,draw}]{
       &    & N5 & N9  \\
       & N2 & N6 & N10 \\
     N1 & N3 & N7 & N11 \\
       & N4 & N8 &     \\
   };   
\node[draw=red!70!black,fill=red!20,fit={(A-3-1) (A-2-2) (A-4-2)}] {};
\foreach \Pos/\Nodo in {A-3-1/N1,A-2-2/N2,A-3-2/N3,A-4-2/N4}
  \node[inner] at (\Pos) {\Nodo};
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

For more complicated paths, I thought about using the nice `\convexhull` command defined by **Jake** in [his answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/27185/3954) to [padded boundary of convex hull](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/27171/3954); however, as of version 3.0.0 of PGF/TikZ, Jake's code no longer works. I used a variation of the simple \draw approach illustrated above and also, a `to[bend=...]` approach similar to the one used by **jackal** in [his answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/104212/3954) to the same question:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix,fit,calc}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[
   inner/.style={circle,draw=blue!50,fill=blue!20,thick,inner sep=3pt},
   outer/.style={draw=green,fill=green!20,thick,inner sep=10pt, column sep=1cm, row sep=1cm}
]
  \matrix (A) [matrix of nodes, outer, nodes={inner,draw}]{
       &    & N5 & N9  \\
       & N2 & N6 & N10 \\
    N1 & N3 & N7 & N11 \\
       & N4 & N8 &     \\
   };
\draw[cyan,fill=cyan!20,rounded corners] 
  ([xshift=-10pt]A-3-1.north west) -- 
  ([xshift=-10pt,yshift=10pt]A-2-2.north west) -- 
  ([xshift=10pt,yshift=10pt]A-2-2.north east) -- 
  ([xshift=10pt,yshift=-10pt]A-2-2.south east) -- 
  ([xshift=10pt]A-3-1.north east) -- 
  ([xshift=10pt]A-3-1.south east) -- 
  ([xshift=10pt,yshift=10pt]A-4-2.north east) -- 
  ([xshift=10pt,yshift=-10pt]A-4-2.south east) -- 
  ([xshift=-10pt,yshift=-10pt]A-4-2.south west) -- 
  ([xshift=-10pt]A-3-1.south west) -- cycle;
\foreach \Pos/\Nodo in {A-3-1/N1,A-2-2/N2,A-3-2/N3,A-4-2/N4}
  \node[inner] at (\Pos) {\Nodo};
\end{tikzpicture}\hfill
\begin{tikzpicture}[
   inner/.style={circle,draw=blue!50,fill=blue!20,thick,inner sep=3pt},
   outer/.style={draw=green,fill=green!20,thick,inner sep=10pt, column sep=1cm, row sep=1cm}
]
  \matrix (A) [matrix of nodes, outer, nodes={inner,draw}]{
       &    & N5 & N9  \\
       & N2 & N6 & N10 \\
    N1 & N3 & N7 & N11 \\
       & N4 & N8 &     \\
   };
\path[draw=red!20,line width=1.4cm, line cap=round, line join=round] 
([xshift=10pt]A-3-1.west) to[bend left=20] (A-2-2.east) 
     to[bend right=30] ([xshift=-10pt]A-3-1.east) 
     to[bend right=30] (A-4-2.east)
     to[bend left=20] ([xshift=10pt]A-3-1.west) -- cycle;
\foreach \Pos/\Nodo in {A-3-1/N1,A-2-2/N2,A-3-2/N3,A-4-2/N4}
  \node[inner] at (\Pos) {\Nodo};
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Awesome! Would there be an easy way to modify this to "wrap around" elements? For instance, what if you didn't want to include N3?

Comment: @i_thought_i_was_smart please see my updated answer.