# How to "outline" a path in TiKZ?

Tags: tikz-pgf, nodes, node-connections

I have a drawing in TiKZ (of a graph, say) and I want to highlight two paths in the drawing. Is there a way to do that using my already-defined node names, without explicitly making new coordinates?

I can almost get there by making my extra paths go through node anchors, but I'd like to offset the paths farther away from the nodes than where the anchors are.

(I've attached a minimal example below. Ideally, I'd like both the red and blue paths to be on the outside of the triangle.)

```
\documentclass{article} 
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgf}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usetikzlibrary{calc, through}
\tikzstyle{vertex}=[circle, draw, inner sep=1pt, minimum size=6pt, fill=black!20]

\begin{document}    
\begin{tikzpicture}
\foreach \i in {0,1,2}{\node[vertex] (\i) at (\i*120:1) {};}
\node[vertex] (4) at (2,0){};
\draw (0) --(1) --(2) -- (0);
\draw[dashed] (0) -- (4);
\draw[red, rounded corners] (4.north) -- (0.north) -- (1.north east) --(1.west) -- (2.west); 
\draw[blue, rounded corners] (1.south east) -- (2.south east) -- (0.south) --(4.south); 
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: mwe image]

Comment: Similar to http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/27171/padded-boundary-of-convex-hull?

Comment: You can use already existing coordinates and `shift` them according your needs: `draw ([yshift=3pt]4.north)--([yshift=3pt]0.north) ... `. You can use `xshift=...`, `yshift=...` or `shift={(...,...)}` (don't forget `{` and `}` with last one).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you put both on the outside, one with partially overwrite the other, won't it?

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgf}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usetikzlibrary{calc, through}
\tikzstyle{vertex}=[circle, draw, inner sep=1pt, minimum size=6pt, fill=black!20]

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\foreach \i in {0,1,2}{\node[vertex] (\i) at (\i*120:1) {};}
\node[vertex] (4) at (2,0){};
\draw (0) --(1) --(2) -- (0);
\draw[dashed] (0) -- (4);
\draw[red, rounded corners=1pt] (4.north) -- (0.north)-- (1.north east) -- (1.north) --(1.north west) -- (1.west) -- (2.west);
\draw[blue, rounded corners=1pt] (1.west) -- (2.west) -- (2.south west) -- (2.south) -- (2.south east) -- (0.south) --(4.south);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: Triangle]

So you could use the `positioning` library to fine tune the spacing and avoid the second path overwriting the first:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgf}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usetikzlibrary{calc, through, positioning}
\tikzstyle{vertex}=[circle, draw, inner sep=1pt, minimum size=6pt, fill=black!20]

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[node distance=.1mm]
\foreach \i in {0,1,2}{\node[vertex] (\i) at (\i*120:1) {};}
\node[vertex] (4) at (2,0){};
\draw (0) --(1) --(2) -- (0);
\draw[dashed] (0) -- (4);
\draw[red, rounded corners=1pt] (4.north) -- (0.north)-- (1.north east) -- (1.north) --(1.north west) -- (1.west) -- (2.west);
\node (a) [left=of 1.west] {};
\node (b) [left=of 2.west] {};
\path [draw, blue, rounded corners=1pt] (a.east) -- (b.east) -- (2.south west) -- (2.south) -- (2.south east) -- (0.south) --(4.south);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: Distinct paths]

or, setting the `node distance=.25mm`:

[image: More distinct paths]

To change the node distance only locally so that it does not affect the location of other nodes in a complex diagram, you can limit the scope of the setting. For example, in this diagram, I limit the setting of `node distance=.25mm` and illustrate this by placing another node `z` after the scope of the setting has ended:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgf}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usetikzlibrary{calc, through, positioning}
\tikzstyle{vertex}=[circle, draw, inner sep=1pt, minimum size=6pt, fill=black!20]

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\foreach \i in {0,1,2}{\node[vertex] (\i) at (\i*120:1) {};}
\node[vertex] (4) at (2,0){};
\draw (0) --(1) --(2) -- (0);
\draw[dashed] (0) -- (4);
\draw[red, rounded corners=1pt] (4.north) -- (0.north)-- (1.north east) -- (1.north) --(1.north west) -- (1.west) -- (2.west);
{\tikzset{node distance=.25mm}
\node (a) [left=of 1.west] {};
\node (b) [left=of 2.west] {};
\path [draw, blue, rounded corners=1pt] (a.east) -- (b.east) -- (2.south west) -- (2.south) -- (2.south east) -- (0.south) --(4.south);}
\node (c) [left=of 1.west] {z};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: z to left with standard setting of node distance]

Note that the only difference between

```
\node (a) [left=of 1.west] {};
```

and

```
\node (c) [left=of 1.west] {z};
```

as regards location is that the former is within the scope of `\tikzset{node distance=.25mm}` whereas the latter is not and therefore uses the default setting.

Comment: Yes. I need them to *not* overlap---I need to be able to see both paths.

Comment: @LeahWrennBerman See edits. I think the slightly larger spacing is preferable but you can obviously adjust to suit.

Comment: That's a nice solution---and your using all the anchors to go around the node is helpful---but it doesn't really play nice with other relatively-positioned nodes on more complicated graphs. :(

Comment: @LeahWrennBerman Well I changed `node distance` for the whole picture but if you have other relatively-positioned nodes obviously you wouldn't want to do that and would instead specify it locally, wouldn't you?

Comment: I'm sure---if I knew how to do that!

Comment: @LeahWrennBerman See my edit. Does that help at all? The `z` is just to demonstrate that the default `node distance` isn't affected.