# Definition conditional on pgfversion

Tags: tikz-pgf, conditionals

Due to a [change in behaviour between versions of pgf](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/27171/padded-boundary-of-convex-hull#comment383409_27185), I want to introduce a conditional definition that depends on whether or not `\pgfversion` >= 3. How can I do this?

Comment: Although not technically a duplicate question, I realised the answer was contained here: http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/13309/245