# How to circle a complex set of nodes and fill the surface

Tags: tikz-pgf

I'm trying to circle a set of nodes in a graph in such way that it is nice and I can fill the surface.

I've tried `plot[smooth cycle]` but is leads to mitigated results. I've also tried to use `\shade` and `\fill` but I think my border paths are not connected very well...

Could you give me some ideas?

Here is the graph and the kind of circle I would like to get.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows,automata,calc}

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
\footnotesize
\begin{tikzpicture}[->,>=stealth',auto,semithick]

    \tikzstyle{every state}=[fill=none,draw=black,text=black]
    \tikzset{ficti/.style={draw=none,text=black,fill=none}}
    \tikzset{mycut/.style={thick,double,-}}

    \node[state,fill=gray] (SRC) [] {$src$};
    \node[state,node distance=1.60cm] (S10) [right of=SRC] {$1_0$};
    \node[state,node distance=1.20cm] (S20) [below of=S10] {$2_0$};
    \node[state,node distance=1.20cm] (S30) [below of=S20] {$3_0$};
    \node[state,node distance=1.20cm] (S40) [below of=S30] {$4_0$};
    \node[state,node distance=1.90cm] (S21) [right of=S20] {$2_1$};
    \node[state,node distance=1.90cm] (S31) [right of=S30] {$3_1$};
    \node[state,node distance=1.90cm] (S22) [right of=S21] {$2_2$};
    \node[state,node distance=1.90cm] (S32) [right of=S31] {$3_2$};
    \node[state,node distance=5.70cm] (S41) [right of=S40] {$4_1$};
    \node[state,node distance=1.90cm] (S42) [right of=S41] {$4_2$};
    \node[ficti,node distance=4.70cm] (F01) [right of=S10] {};
    \node[state,node distance=0.50cm] (S50) [above of=F01] {$5_0$};
    \node[state,node distance=1.90cm] (S51) [right of=S50] {$5_1$};
    \node[state,node distance=1.90cm] (S52) [right of=S51] {$5_2$};
    \node[state,node distance=5.20cm,fill=gray] (SNK) [right of=F01] {$snk$};

    \draw[mycut] (SRC) ++(90:15pt) coordinate(a1) arc (90:260:15pt) coordinate(a2);
    \draw[mycut] (S20) ++(30:15pt) coordinate(b1) arc (30:85:15pt) coordinate(b2);
    \draw[mycut] (S31) ++(210:15pt) coordinate(c1) arc (210:270:15pt) coordinate(c2);
    \draw[mycut] (S41) ++(60:15pt) coordinate(d1) arc (60:90:15pt) coordinate(d2);
    \draw[mycut] (S42) ++(-115:15pt) coordinate(e1) arc (-115:60:15pt) coordinate(e2);
    \draw[mycut] (a2) to (b2);
    \draw[mycut] (b1) to (c1);
    \draw[mycut] (c2) to (d2);
    \draw[mycut] (d1) to (e1);
    \draw[mycut] plot [smooth] coordinates {(e2) ($(S10)!0.5!(S22)+(0.7,0.70)$) (a1)};

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

[image: results]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! Do you want to fill that whole area delimited by the plot?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Usually, we don't put a greeting or a “thank you” in our posts. While this might seem strange at first, it is not a sign of lack of politeness, but rather part of our trying to keep everything very concise. [Accepting and upvoting answers is the preferred way here](http://tex.stackexchange.com/about) to say “thank you” to users who helped you.

Comment: possible duplicate of [padded boundary of convex hull](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/27171/padded-boundary-of-convex-hull)

Comment: @MaartenDhondt The hull is not convex here. It won't cover this case.

Comment: @MaartenDhondt The boundary is *not* convex here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to fill that area, you're better off using a single draw command and then filling that. Having multiple paths makes it only harder to fill because you need to fill each one of them and you're not even guaranteed a good result anyways.

Some notes:

- You only need one `\tikzset` and then you can group styles inside of it. Also, keep using it instead of `\tikzstyle`.
- `arrows` is considered deprecated (although still supported for those that want to stick with it), so I replaced it with `arrows.meta`. The syntax for arrow tips is a slightly different, but not totally. See the [Tikz Manual](http://ctan.mirror.garr.it/mirrors/CTAN/graphics/pgf/base/doc/pgfmanual.pdf) for more information.

### Output

[image: figure 1]

### Code

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta,automata,calc, backgrounds}

\tikzset{
    every state/.style={fill=none,draw=black,text=black},
    ficti/.style={draw=none,text=black,fill=none},
    mycut/.style={thick,double,-}
}

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
\footnotesize
\begin{tikzpicture}[->,-{Stealth},auto,semithick]


    \node[state,fill=gray] (SRC) [] {$src$};
    \node[state,node distance=1.60cm] (S10) [right of=SRC] {$1_0$};
    \node[state,node distance=1.20cm] (S20) [below of=S10] {$2_0$};
    \node[state,node distance=1.20cm] (S30) [below of=S20] {$3_0$};
    \node[state,node distance=1.20cm] (S40) [below of=S30] {$4_0$};
    \node[state,node distance=1.90cm] (S21) [right of=S20] {$2_1$};
    \node[state,node distance=1.90cm] (S31) [right of=S30] {$3_1$};
    \node[state,node distance=1.90cm] (S22) [right of=S21] {$2_2$};
    \node[state,node distance=1.90cm] (S32) [right of=S31] {$3_2$};
    \node[state,node distance=5.70cm] (S41) [right of=S40] {$4_1$};
    \node[state,node distance=1.90cm] (S42) [right of=S41] {$4_2$};
    \node[ficti,node distance=4.70cm] (F01) [right of=S10] {};
    \node[state,node distance=0.50cm] (S50) [above of=F01] {$5_0$};
    \node[state,node distance=1.90cm] (S51) [right of=S50] {$5_1$};
    \node[state,node distance=1.90cm] (S52) [right of=S51] {$5_2$};
    \node[state,node distance=5.20cm,fill=gray] (SNK) [right of=F01] {$snk$};

\begin{scope}[on background layer]
\filldraw[mycut, top color=cyan!50, bottom color=blue!50!black] (SRC) ++(90:15pt) coordinate(a1)
        arc (90:260:15pt) 
        -- ($(S20)+(90:15pt)$)
        arc (85:30:15pt)
        -- ($(S31)+(210:15pt)$)
        arc (210:270:15pt)
        -- ($(S41)+(90:15pt)$)
        arc (90:60:15pt)
        -- ($(S42)+(-115:15pt)$)
        arc (-115:60:15pt) [rounded corners=1cm]
        -- (S21.east|-a1) [sharp corners] -- cycle;
\end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```