# "ifthenelse" causing problems in tikz - convexhull

Tags: tikz-pgf

I am trying to make the "convexhull" code from [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/27171/padded-boundary-of-convex-hull) to work for both pgf/tikz 3.0 and older versions work (the definition of atan changed from version 2.9 to 3.0). However, so far I have failed to do so.

In the preamble I defined

```
\newboolean{curr_tikzv}    
\makeatletter
\@ifpackagelater{tikz}{2013/12/01}
 { \setboolean{curr_tikzv}{true}}
 { \setboolean{curr_tikzv}{false}
}
\makeatother
```

and I replaced the critical definitions of \n1 and \n2 by

```
    \n1 = {\ifthenelse{\boolean{curr_tikzv}}{atan2(\y1,\x1) + 90}{atan2(\x1,\y1) + 90}},
```

and the corresp. change for \n2.
Yet this produces an error, claiming there are unmatched "}".

What am I doing wrong? The first error message I get is

```
! Argument of \XC@definec@lor has an extra }.
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`\ifthenelse` is *not* expandable and is not supported in the setting argument for `\n1`. A simple `\if` switch should work:

```
\newif\ifCurrTikzV
\makeatletter
\@ifpackagelater{tikz}{2013/12/01}{\CurrTikzVtrue}{\CurrTikzVfalse}
\makeatother

\n1 = {\ifCurrTikzV atan2(\y1,\x1) + 90\else atan2(\x1,\y1) + 90\fi},
```

Instead of `\ifCurrTikzV` for each `atan2`, a macro could be defined:

```
\makeatletter
\@ifpackagelater{tikz}{2013/12/01}{%
  \def\AtanTwo(#1,#2){atan2({#1},{#2})}%
}{%
  \def\AtanTwo(#1,#2){atan2({#2},{#1})}%
}
\makeatother

\n1 = {\AtanTwo(\y1,\x1) + 90},
```

Comment: Thank you very much. I especially like your second solution. Is there a reason why \ifthenelse is not expandable?

Comment: @john_leo `\ifthenelse` contains assignments, groups, redefine macros, ... The extended syntax has its price.