# Hyperarcs with Tikz

Tags: tikz-pgf, graphs

I would like to draw hyperarcs with tikz, with one head node and several tails.
Something like this:

[image: Hyperarc]

However I did not find how to do this, and I am not sure how I could write such a command in tikz.

Comment: what is hyper about this arc? I don't see any arcs but anyway

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! You should show some your effort to draw this picture. It can be drawn with simple `\draw (<coordinate1>) (<coordinate2>) ... ;` commands.

Comment: You may start by drawing a [padded convex hull](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/27171/padded-boundary-of-convex-hull) and then alter it at the end to draw the arrow tip.