# Parsing non-comma-separated lists in TikZ environment

Tags: tikz-pgf, loops, comma-separated-list

In [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/27185/203616) I saw that we can use `[<new pgf key>/.code={...}, <new pgf key>]` to smuggle in some code into the construction of a TikZ path. This approach works if all coordinates have a label because the standard arrays are comma-separated. I was thinking that the `listofitems` package could be used to process lists of coordinates without labels by changing the separator. However, the below code throws an error during path construction and I don't quite understand why.

The polyline simply serves as a means of illustration in an MWE. I am trying to understand more generally how to iterate over lists from the `listofitems` package in a Tikz environment.

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz, listofitems}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}

\newcommand{\polyline}[2][,]{
    \setsepchar{#1}
    \readlist*\inputlist{#2}
    [create coords/.code={
        \foreach \i in {1, ..., \inputlistlen} {
            \coordinate (coord\i) at (\inputlist[\i]);
        }
    }, create coords]
    (coord1)
    \foreach \i in {2, ..., \inputlistlen} {
        -- (coord\i)
    }
}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw \polyline[:]{0,0: 1,0};
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you follow this path, use the trick also to smuggle the macro into the path. And use styles.

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz, listofitems}

\newcommand{\polyline}[2][,]{
    \setsepchar{#1}
    \readlist*\inputlist{#2}
    \tikzset{insert path={foreach \i in {1, ..., \inputlistlen} 
    {({\inputlist[\i]}) coordinate (coord\i)}
    plot[samples at={1, ..., \inputlistlen}] (coord\x)}}
}
\tikzset{polyline/.code={\expandafter\polyline#1}}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw [polyline={[:]{0,0: 1,0: 3,2}}];
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I am not versed in `tikz`, but by moving the `\draw` into the macro (as an argument), you can make it work.

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz, listofitems}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}

\newcommand{\polyline}[3][,]{
    \setsepchar{#1}
    \readlist*\inputlist{#3}
    [create coords/.code={
       \foreach \i in {1, ..., \inputlistlen} {
            \coordinate (coord\i) at (\inputlist[\i]);
        }
    }, create coords]
    #2 (coord1)
    \foreach \i in {2, ..., \inputlistlen} {
        -- (coord\i)
    }
}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\polyline[:]\draw{0,1: 1,0};
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Clearly, though, the problem with the OP's MWE is that after the `\draw` command is issued, the `\polyline` is performing a bunch of setup code that the `\draw` macro is not expecting.  So, an alternative would be to break it into two macros:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz, listofitems}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}

\newcommand{\polylineinput}[2][,]{
    \setsepchar{#1}
    \readlist*\inputlist{#2}
    [create coords/.code={
       \foreach \i in {1, ..., \inputlistlen} {
            \coordinate (coord\i) at (\inputlist[\i]);
        }
    }, create coords]
}
\newcommand{\polyline}{
     (coord1)
    \foreach \i in {2, ..., \inputlistlen} {
        -- (coord\i)
    }
}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\polylineinput[:]{0,1: 1,0}
\draw\polyline;
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

A third approach would be to have a single macro `\polylineinput` that creates `\thepolyline` containing `(coord1) -- (coord2)`, so that `\draw\thepolyline` could then be issued:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz, listofitems}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}

\newcommand{\polylineinput}[2][,]{
    \setsepchar{#1}
    \readlist*\inputlist{#2}
    [create coords/.code={
       \foreachitem\z\in\inputlist[] {
            \coordinate (coord\zcnt) at (\z);
        }
    }, create coords]
    \xdef\thepolyline{}
    \foreach \i in {1, ..., \inputlistlen} {
        \ifnum\i>1\relax\xdef\thepolyline{\thepolyline--}\fi
        \xdef\thepolyline{\thepolyline(coord\i)}
    }
}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\polylineinput[:]{0,1: 1,0}
\draw\thepolyline;
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```